# JavaFX Area Chart 100% line

Tags: java, javafx

Ok all you expert FX peeps out there. I need some help adding a dark line at the 100 tick mark spot on an AreaChart.

[image]

As you can see by the picture there at that 100 mark I need a line to go across the sheet to tell everyone whether they're at 100% production or not. The position of that 100 can change from any given week. Sometimes the top value will not be 170 but maybe 150 or so. My current code is as follows but it's just testing this out (and it's also not working correctly).

```
@Override
protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
    super.layoutPlotChildren();
    ObservableList<Node> removeable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    removeable.addAll(getPlotChildren().stream().filter(node -> node instanceof Line).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    getPlotChildren().removeAll(removeable);
    Double y = Double.valueOf(getYAxis().getValueForDisplay(100.0).toString());
    System.out.println(y);
    Line line = new Line();
    line.setStartX(0.0);
    line.setStartY(y);
    line.setEndX(600.0);
    line.setEndY(y);
    getPlotChildren().add(line);
}
```

The chart line is not being placed in the right vertical position (I'm well aware my line doesn't go to the end this is just a test).

[image]

Curious as to what the issue is here and what exactly

```
getYAxis().getValueForDisplay(100.0)
```

is doing.

Comment: That looks like it should work, though you would normally do `double y = getYAxis().getValueForDisplay(100.0)`, instead of converting to a string so that you can convert it back to a double. Can you extend the example to a [MCVE]?

Comment: getYAxis().getValueForDisplay(100.0) returns an FX object of type Y. Y is whatever your Axis is (in my case it is a NumberAxis). There is no conversion to get it to a double (that I saw anyways) so I convert it to a string (whenever you print Y it prints a number that looks like a double) and then to a double. About the example eh, we'll see what I can do when I leave work today.

Comment: Oh, I see it. You want `getDisplayPosition`. You are converting pixel coordinate ls to axis values, instead of axis values to pixel coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Example]

I've solved this issue differently in the past. I used the charts unmodified, and instead added components to the ".chart-content" Pane. These are then aligned to the ".plot-area" component using co-ordinate transforms. This is a fully working example of this approach.

```
public class Horse extends Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Line line;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private Region plotArea;
    private Pane chartContent;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final AreaChart<String, Number> chart = new AreaChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        Series<String, Number> series = new Series<>();
        series.getData().add(new Data<>("foo", 50));
        series.getData().add(new Data<>("bar", 25));
        series.getData().add(new Data<>("baz", 125));

        chart.getData().add(series);

        plotArea = (Region) chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
        chartContent = (Pane) chart.lookup(".chart-content");
        line = new Line();
        chartContent.getChildren().add(line);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(chart));
        primaryStage.show();

        chart.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            update();
        });
        plotArea.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            update();
        });
        update();

    }

    private void update() {
        double location = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(100);
        Point2D a = plotArea.localToScene(new Point2D(0, location));
        Point2D b = plotArea.localToScene(new Point2D(plotArea.getWidth(), location));

        Point2D aTrans = chartContent.sceneToLocal(a);
        Point2D bTrans = chartContent.sceneToLocal(b);

        line.setStartX(aTrans.getX());
        line.setStartY(aTrans.getY());
        line.setEndX(bTrans.getX());
        line.setEndY(bTrans.getY());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam I appreciate your response. I actually neglected "getDisplayPosition" which is exactly what I needed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting pixel values to axis values with  `getValueForDisplay()`. You want to convert axis values to pixel values with `getDisplayPosition()`.

Replace

```
Double y = Double.valueOf(getYAxis().getValueForDisplay(100.0).toString());
```

with

```
double y = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(100.0);
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartWithHorizontal extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        LineChart<String, Number> chart = new LineChart<String, Number>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis()) {

//          Line line = new Line();
//          
//          @Override
//          protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
//              super.layoutPlotChildren();
//              getPlotChildren().remove(line);
//              line.setStartX(0);
//              line.setEndX(600);
//              double y = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(100.0);
//              line.setStartY(y);
//              line.setEndY(y);
//              getPlotChildren().add(line);
//          }

            @Override
            protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
                super.layoutPlotChildren();
                ObservableList<Node> removeable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                removeable.addAll(getPlotChildren().stream().filter(node -> node instanceof Line).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                getPlotChildren().removeAll(removeable);
                double y = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(100.0);
                System.out.println(y);
                Line line = new Line();
                line.setStartX(0.0);
                line.setStartY(y);
                line.setEndX(600.0);
                line.setEndY(y);
                getPlotChildren().add(line);
            }
        };

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 4; i++) {
            Series<String, Number> s = new Series<>();
            s.setName("Data "+i);
            chart.getData().add(s);
        }
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 6; i++) {
            for (int s = 0 ; s < 4 ; s++) {
                chart.getData().get(s).getData().add(new Data<>("Item "+i, rng.nextDouble()*200));
            }
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(chart, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

A more natural (to me, anyway) approach is shown in the commented code.

Comment: Yes I noticed by reading everyone's posts. Thank you for your help the problem is done (finally). My problem is a tiny bit different than your code simply because I created a separate class for the AreaChart and needed generic parameters (instead of String and Number) because I use it for multiple charts but I just simply cast the yAxis to a NumberAxis for that chart only. Also about the minimal, complete, verified example my project is quite complex and I'm not used to needing help so I wasn't really sure how to post a complete code example.